# Xcode UIView background like TableView grouped

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I want my UIView to have the same background like the TableView background when tableview is grouped. i mean the striped blue background :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Docs next time:

```
[UIColor groupedTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/groupTableViewBackgroundColor

Comment: On an iPad the background **isn't** striped because a grouped tableView isn't striped.

Comment: I saw now its deprecated. What to do now?

Comment: You have to make the background. Create or find an image like the old one and use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`. It's no longer a provided system color. you have to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the view's background color to `[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`.

Comment: Sorry to be not clear enough. i wanted to know how it works in the interface builder :)

Comment: if i set it like you postet here, the background is black :(

Comment: I saw now its deprecated. What to do now?

Comment: The only alternative is taking a screenshot of the background, cropping it to getting a tileable image from it, and using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]` to set the background color.